# Como aplicar estilos sobre un elemento <a> cuya referencia esta siendo visitada

Tags: html, css

Estoy haciendo un *slider* con solo `css` y `html` a traves del siguiente metodo ...

```css
.city_slider_imgs
{
    background-color : #0f0;
    height : auto;
    height : 50em;
    margin : 50px;
}
:root
{
    scroll-behavior: smooth;
}

a
{
    text-decoration: none !important;
}

.img_container> img
{
    width : 50em;
    height : 50em;
    position : absolute;
    object-fit : contain;
    opacity: 0;
    left : 0%;
    transition-property: opacity;
    transition-duration : .3s;
}


.img_container > img:target
{
    opacity: 1;
}
.ref_input
{
    display: none;
}
.slider_controler
{
    background-color : rgb(44, 173, 44);
    display : inline-flex;
    border-radius: 10px;
    position : sticky;
    top: 10%;
    left: 20%;
    margin : 10px;
    z-index : 99;
    justify-content :center;
    padding : 10px;
}

.slider_controler > *
{
    padding : 10px;
    background-color : rgb(29, 206, 29);
    margin : 10px;
    border-radius : 10px;
    transition-property: transform;
    transition-duration : .3s;
    transform: scale(1, 1);
    color : #fff;
}



.slider_controler > *:hover
{
    transform: scale(1.5, 1.5);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css.css">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <section class="imgs_section" id ="imgs_section">
        <h2 class = "section_title"> Images de la universidad, region y egresados notables </h2>
        <div class="city_slider_imgs" id = "city_slider_imgs_id">
            <div class = "slider_controler">
                <a href = "#img1"> 1 </a>
                <a href = "#img2"> 2 </a>
                <a href = "#img3"> 3 </a>
            </div>
            <div class="img_container">
                <img id = "img1" src = "<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css.css">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <section class="imgs_section" id ="imgs_section">
        <h2 class = "section_title"> Images de la universidad, region y egresados notables </h2>
        <div class="city_slider_imgs" id = "city_slider_imgs_id">
            <div class = "slider_controler">
                <a href = "#img1"> 1 </a>
                <a href = "#img2"> 2 </a>
                <a href = "#img3"> 3 </a>
            </div>
            <div class="img_container">
                <img id = "img1" src = "lorempixel.com/400/200" alt = "no se ha encontrado la imagen" title = "ciudad_1">
                <img id = "img2" src = "lorempixel.com/400/200" alt = "no se ha encontrado la imagen" title = "ciudad_1">
                <img id = "img3" src = "lorempixel.com/400/200" alt = "no se ha encontrado la imagen" title = "ciudad_1">
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
</body>
</html>
" alt = "no se ha encontrado la imagen" title = "ciudad_1">
                <img id = "img2" src = "../../material/1542113135_776401_1542116070_noticia_normal.jpg" alt = "no se ha encontrado la imagen" title = "ciudad_1">
                <img id = "img3" src = "../../material/imagen_de_universidad.jpg" alt = "no se ha encontrado la imagen" title = "ciudad_1">
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
</body>
</html>
```

El ejemplo quedo algo raro, el caso esta en que necesito alguna `pseudo-clase` que referencie a los elementos `a` cuando la terminacion de la url sea la del elemento al que estos referencian, de modo que cuando se este viendo una imagen ( es decir, que la terminacion de la url sea la misma que el id de la imagen ), el boton que la referencie adquiera un estilo diferente para diferenciar . Alguna idea?

Comment: El ejemplo quedo tan raro que no es ni mínimo ni verificable; no se ve ni la funcionalidad ni el problema. Y la redacción tampoco ayuda.

Answer (score 1):

Si quieres cambiar el estilo cuando cambie el fragmento de la url (#fragmento) puedes usar el evento `onhashchange` para agregar/quitar un clase en particular.

```js
window.onhashchange = function(){
  let e = document.querySelector('a.mostrando')
  if(e) 
    e.classList.remove('mostrando')
  e = document.querySelector('a[href="'+window.location.hash+'"]')
  e.classList.add('mostrando');
}
```

```css
.slider_controler > a.mostrando{
  background-color : black;
}

.city_slider_imgs{
    background-color : #0f0;
    height : auto;
    height : 50em;
    margin : 50px;
}
:root{
    scroll-behavior: smooth;
}

a{
    text-decoration: none !important;
}

.img_container> img{
    width : 50em;
    height : 50em;
    position : absolute;
    object-fit : contain;
    opacity: 0;
    left : 0%;
    transition-property: opacity;
    transition-duration : .3s;
}

.img_container > img:target{
    opacity: 1;
}
.ref_input{
    display: none;
}
.slider_controler{
    background-color : rgb(44, 173, 44);
    display : inline-flex;
    border-radius: 10px;
    position : sticky;
    top: 10%;
    left: 20%;
    margin : 10px;
    z-index : 99;
    justify-content :center;
    padding : 10px;
}

.slider_controler > *{
    padding : 10px;
    background-color : rgb(29, 206, 29);
    margin : 10px;
    border-radius : 10px;
    transition-property: transform;
    transition-duration : .3s;
    transform: scale(1, 1);
    color : #fff;
}

.slider_controler > *:hover{
    transform: scale(1.5, 1.5);
}
```

```html
    <section class="imgs_section" id ="imgs_section">
        <div class="city_slider_imgs" id = "city_slider_imgs_id">
            <div class = "slider_controler">
                <a href = "#img1"> 1 </a>
                <a href = "#img2"> 2 </a>
                <a href = "#img3"> 3 </a>
            </div>
            <div class="img_container">
                <img id = "img1" src = "https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2020/12/03/05/24/lion-5799526_960_720.jpg">
                <img id = "img2" src = "https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2020/01/04/23/27/mountain-4741994_960_720.jpg">
                <img id = "img3" src = "https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2021/07/29/20/47/church-6508068_960_720.jpg">
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
```

Sin embargo, parece más conveniente manejarlo desde el mismo controlador javascript del slider.

Comment: la idea era no usar nada de JS, ya que, basicamente no se nada :|, sin embargo voy a aprender js para hacer este slider, gracias igualmente